# How to fix Netbeans 8.1 double icons on plank

Tags: plank, icons

I downloaded and installed Neatbeans 8.1 from the official site. Even if I tick **Keep in Dock** for the Netbeans icon, a new icon is generated every time I click on it. This new icon doesn't have the option to **Keep in Dock**, only **Close**.

I googled a bit and came to know about .desktop files in /usr/share/applications

However, there is no .desktop file for netbeans!

Help?

Update: I copied the .desktop file from `~/.local/share/applications` to `/usr/share/applications`

I guess the only problem remaining is figuring out the WM_CLASS of Netbeans 8.1

But when I run this command:

> xprop WM_CLASS

as suggested in the other question, it returns **WM_CLASS: not found**

So how to find that out?

Comment: I updated the question. Please check it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `StartupWMClass=NetBeans IDE 8.1`

[Source.](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=183739)

Comment: short, precise but works =)

Comment: Just to clarify this should be added on a new line in the netbeans **.desktop** file found in ~/.local/applications or /usr/share/applications